# Is there a way to use "netsh trace" on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I tried to run this command on a machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Core:

```
netsh trace start scenario=netconnection capture=yes report=yes
```

but it returned this message:

```
The following command was not found: trace start scenario=netconnection capture=yes report=yes
```

So I ran `netsh help`, to list available commands, which confirmed that `trace` is not available. Is there a way to use `trace` on Server Core, or an alternative offering similar functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. Trace is not available in Server Core.

There are alternate tools that may allow a similar result. For instance, others have had success using nmcap to perform similar tasks, and you can install Network Monitor which contains nmcap on a Server Core system.